# Trouble with unicode-math/fontspec in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

The following MWE yields a wrong output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xltxtra}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\(\sigma \gets 1\)
\end{document}
```

The expected output should be obvious. Unfortunately though, the “gets” arrow is dropped from the output when rendered with XeTeX (0.9997.4, Unicode-Math v0.5b):

> 1

But even weirder, when I comment in the `\setmainfont` line and comment out the `\setmathfont` line, then the result looks as follows:

> ← 1

i.e. the sigma is swallowed.

Summary: when trying to use either Asana Math or Linux Libertine or both I cannot get the above text to display correctly.

**Is this a bug? How can I get this to display correctly?**

---

Furthermore, when I have “Asana Math” loaded, additionally load `microype` (2.5 beta 0.4) *and* display a very huge math text (e.g. `fontsize{50}{50}`), the `xelatex` compiler creates an error and doesn’t produce any output. This is the error log:

> thesis.tex:13: [Font] Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <50> not available size <24.88> substituted. (page 1)
>   thesis.tex:13: [Font] Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <34.99985> not available size <24.88> substituted. (page 1)
>   thesis.tex:13: [Font] Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <50> not available size <24.88> substituted. (page 1)
>   thesis.tex:13: [Font] Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <34.99985> not available size <24.88> substituted. (page 1)

– I understand this error, but why does `xelatex` fail so badly and doesn’t produce any output?

Comment: I should note that this particular problem can be solved rather easily by a simple `\renewcommand*\gets{←}` but I don’t know which other characters aren’t working.

Comment: That is more or less what unicode-math was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/issue/149) that has been [fixed](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/ae03ca3ef8e581ab430771448cedeb2abd0782a9) last October, but the fix doesn't seem to have propagated to CTAN yet (or at least not into TeX Live).
With `unicode-math` from [git](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/) your code works as expected (at least the arrow part).

Comment: @Caramdir — Ah. I'd better do something about this `:)`

Comment: Drat, for some reason the TeX Live installation can’t find this package when I install it in `TEXMFLOCAL`, even though the same works seamlessly for other packages … but this is the correct answer so I’ve accepted it.

Comment: @Konrad: please report that as a bug. `unicode-math` *should* work like other packages.

Comment: @Philipp: that’s not an issue with `unicode-math`, the package is put into the correct location (I’m doing a manual install via `make  install-sys`). But somehow kpathsea refuses to pick up this path, as evidenced by `kpsewhich unicode-math.sty` returning the `texmf-dist` path instead of `texmf-local` (but for other packages that exist in both paths this works). I blame my own stupidity.

Comment: @Konrad: Did you run `mktexlsr` afterwards? (Probably the makefile should do this automatically.)

Comment: @Philipp: duh. It worked after `mktexlsr`. I somehow thought this wasn’t necessary anymore. (EDIT: oh, just like you suggested.)

Answer (score 5):

Your example works for me with the latest [unicode-math's nighty-build](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math).
Another solution is to use `\leftarrow` instead of `\gets`.
The comprehensive [list of symbols](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) for unicode-math may also be helpful for this kind of problems.

Comment: Carmdir has been a little faster than me. So instead of delete my post I've added a link for the unicode-math list of symbols.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, thanks for the welcome and for the tip (and of course for the edit)

Answer (score 1):

microtype is not compatible with xelatex, unless that has been updated relatively recently (in the last few months).

you also say you're  trying to use unicode math, but you are not using unicode in your example. the unicode symbol would be the sigma symbol, not \sigma.

Comment: I’m using version 2.5 (beta) which *is* compatible with XeTeX. You’re right about my not using Unicode but I still expect this code to work (and `unicode-math` is required for `\setmathfont`).

Comment: As far as I know `σ` and `\sigma` are equivalent with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Caramdir — Yep, it is correct to use either (and sometimes even preferable to use `\sigma` depending on your text editor and whether other people need to use the code — e.g., copying a maths expression into a totally different pdfLaTeX document).

Comment: well I stand corrected. Microtype support for xetex and xelatex is an excellent feature addition. :P